# Java throw exception at class method

Tags: java, exception

I have question on Java throw exception at class method definition:

```
public void someMethod () throws SomeException {
 try{
   ...
 }catch (SomeException e ){
   ....
 }
}
```

When we declare `throw SomeException` at the method declaration, do we still have to `try/catch` in the body or, can we just use  `throw new SomeException` like this:

```
public void someMethod () throws SomeException {
  // do something
  throw new SomeException() ;
}
```

what is the **correct** way to throw exception when we have `throw Exception` at the method declaration.

Comment: You can test it by writing code and compiling it. By the way think of what does it mean to declare throws clause in method signature?

Answer (score 5):

No, you do not need to catch the exception that you throw as long as you're not changing it or selectively throwing it only in some situations when the exception occurs. So this is often perfectly fine:

```
public void someMethod () throws SomeException {
  // do something
  throw new SomeException() ;
}
```

Although it's often good to give your SomeException class a constructor that takes a String parameter, and then pass that String to the super constructor to allow your exception to be able to pass more information through.

Answer (score 1):

Your prototype `public void someMethod () throws SomeException` is mandating that `someMethod` will only throw exceptions of type `SomeException`. (Or any exception classes derived from `SomeException`).

Therefore you do not need to catch that particular exception in your function, but you will need to catch all others.